# Need to draw US counties on MAP by polygon at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I have a counties DB which has all counties of US with POLY coordinates. Total is around 3214 counties. And every county has several thousands of POLY coordinates. I can draw some of the counties. But when I try to draw all counties, browser is going sleepy and keep loading and loading. Can anyone help me to solve my issue by any algorithm for this?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recomend either using WEAVE

http://oicweave.org/

or Google's mapping tools:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes

Oterwise, You could draw the counties using PHP as PNG images with transparencies and overlay them on you map as needed.  Uses the GD Library to create images of all your counties (or even groups of counties) and save them for future use.

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/fun-with-the-php-gd-library-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for your reply Hoytman. I understand your suggestion. But how its possible to make image for every county and how can I get exact position for country to put image? And I have to fetch details from MySQL first. Hope you understand my requirement. And Thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is single-threaded.  IF you give it a large task to do, it will `freeze` the interface until it has finished (or it times out with an error.)

The only thing you can do is to have it draw things in smaller chunks.

Rough p-code.

```
var counties = [
   // Your data here
];

var countyIdx = 0;

function drawNext() {
  var county = counties[countyIdx];
  // Draw county

  // Advance to the next county
  countyIdx++;
  if (county < counties.length) {
    window.setTimeout(drawNext, 50);
  }
}

// Kick it off
drawNext();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Jeremy. But I need to dray polygon on map. Let me explain my requirement in little in detail. We have to draw all counties on map. First time, all counties will be come in plain color. And once it will marked from admin, that county will be colored with orange color. I hope this req make sense to you.

Comment: The requirement does.  I was, however, when you said "*sleepy and keep loading and loading*", I was taking a guess that you meant the browser stalled and operation timed out.  If that is the case, this general solution still works, you just have to figure out what part of your code things are stalling at.  That's something you'll need to figure out, either with the profiler or other debugging tools.